# how do I find an object's index number in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've got this code that is looking for the closest number to 0 in my array :

```
var tideArray = new Array();  
tideArray.push({tide:"haute", difference: "-14"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"haute", difference: "3"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"basse", difference: "-4"});  
tideArray.push({tide:"basse", difference: "8"});  

if (tideArray.length > 0)  
{  
    var minItem: Object = tideArray[0];  
    for (var index:int = 1; index < tideArray.length; index++)  
    {  
        if (Math.abs(tideArray[index].difference) < Math.abs(minItem.difference))  
        {  
            minItem = tideArray[index];  
        }  
    }  
}  

trace(minItem.difference) // OUTPUT is 3 in this case
```

s there a way to find the index of `minItem.difference` in my `tideArray` ? (so, the result here should be index = 1 )

I've tried `tideArray.indexOf(minItem.difference)` but the output is `-1`, so the index wasn't found...

I'm looking for the index number and not the value of "difference" or "tide".

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: FYI, you have a bug in your code.  Try swapping the two "haute" values in your tideArray and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using map, e.g.:

```
tideArray.map(function (cv) { return cv.difference }).indexOf("-14")
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple approach would be to record the index using your existing loop:

```
if (tideArray.length > 0)  
{  
    var mindex: int = NaN;
    var minItem: Object = tideArray[0];  
    for (var index:int = 0; index < tideArray.length; index++)  
    {  
        if (Math.abs(tideArray[index].difference) < Math.abs(minItem.difference))  
        {  
            minItem = tideArray[index];  
            mindex = index;
        }  
    }
    trace("Min item index: " + mindex);
}
```